# Read JSON from JavasScript - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, convertapi

I have a JSON response similar to this from ConvertAPI :

```
{
   "ConversionCost":10,
   "Files":[
      {
         "FileName":"somefile_XXX.pdf",
         "FileExt":"pdf",
         "FileSize":63911,
         "FileId":"718cc1XXXXXXXXX5",
         "Url":"https://v2.convertapi.com/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/somefile_XXX.pdf"
      }
   ]
}
```

Where I am trying to extract the ConversionCost by `result.ConversionCost[0]` (the `result.files[0].Url` works fine) in the following script:

```
let convertApi = ConvertApi.auth({secret: '<API_SECRET>'})
let elResult = document.getElementById('result')
let elResultLink = document.getElementById('resultLink')
let elUrl = document.getElementById('urlInput')
elResult.style.display = 'none'

// On file input change, start conversion
document.getElementById('convertBtn').addEventListener('click', async e => {
    elResult.style.display = 'none'
    document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'wait'
    try {

        // Converting web page to PDF file
        let params = convertApi.createParams()
        params.add('url', elUrl.value)
        params.add('FileName', 'The_FileName.pdf');
        params.add('LoadLazyContent', 'true');
        params.add('Zoom', '1.5');
        params.add('PageSize', 'a4');
        params.add('MarginTop', '0');
        params.add('MarginRight', '0');
        params.add('MarginBottom', '0');
        params.add('MarginLeft', '0');
        let result = await convertApi.convert('web', 'pdf', params)


        fetch('some_page.asp?id=315&initials=DDD&pdf_url=' + result.files[0].Url + '&ConversionCost= ' + result.ConversionCost[0]).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }).catch(function() {
          console.log("Booo");
        });

        // Showing link with the result file
        elResultLink.setAttribute('href', result.files[0].Url)
        elResultLink.innerText = result.files[0].Url
        elResult.style.display = 'block'

    } finally {
        document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'default'

    }
})
```

But this  gives me the error in the console `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`

Am I reading it wrong or what am I missing? .. here is the GitHub vor ConvertAPI JS : https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-js

Comment: Is it supposed to be uppercase `result.Files` instead of `result.files`?

Comment: Hi @adiga .. as I have wrote to one of the other responders it is not the files string I am after, that one is working like it should, it is the sibling called ConversionCost I am having struggles reading. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (code not tested):

```
fetch('includes/save_user_welcomeletter_to_server.asp?id=315&initials=DDD&pdf_url=' + result.files[0].Url + '&pdf_ConversionCost= ' + result.ConversionCost)
.then(r => r.json())
.then(o => { 
    // Showing link with the result file
    elResultLink.setAttribute('href', o.files[0].Url)
    elResultLink.innerText = o.files[0].Url
    elResult.style.display = 'block'
    console.log(o.ConversionCost);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Jonas .. The Undefined and NaN is now gone, but the result of console.log and my Request.QueryString("ConversionCost") are both empty.

Answer (score 1):

result.ConversionCost is a Number type but u have used it as a array

Comment: Hi @Taron Qalashyan .. I did try at first just using `result.ConversionCost` but that gives me a Undefined when I write out the Querystring that I am sending it with.

Comment: pls try with this fetch('some_page.asp?id=315&initials=DDD&pdf_url=' + result.Files[0].Url + '&ConversionCost= ' + result.ConversionCost

Comment: That is what I have tried, and that is unfortunately what is giving me the output `Undefined` in Chrome Network tab when doing ` Response.Write Request.QueryString("ConversionCost")` in some_page.asp ..

Comment: other think is that result is clearing after first usage, try this. resutl1 =result and start to use result1

Comment: `let resutl1 = result` and `result1.ConversionCost` gives an `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: result1 is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` error

Comment: can you share API key?, i will try and send you working solution

Comment: you can easily and free sign-up for your own free api here convertapi.com

Answer (score -1):

Based on the response that you given above,

the index named is Files try to use **result.Files[0].Url**

maybe it will work. :)

Comment: Hi @chefboyronron .. I am getting the file info from calling `result.files[0].Url`, but its the ConversionCost I need to extract aswell :-)